# Getting a pointer with auto deduced return type on function template with default template argument

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, auto

The following program makes the pointer `x` on function `g<void>()` having automatically deduced return type:

```
template<class=void>
void g() {}

int main() {
    auto (*x)() = &g;
    (*x)();
}
```

The program is accepted by GCC, but rejected in Clang with the error:

```
error: variable 'x' with type 'auto (*)()' has incompatible initializer of type '<overloaded function type>'
    auto (*x)() = &g;
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s17Mf74Wc

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: `auto (*x)() = &g<void>;` passes though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1soT6Te1W).

Comment: and `template<class=void> auto g() {}` fails [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3ja9K5s79).

Comment: `void (*x)() = &g;` passes also. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5sej5f5PT).

Comment: Even `auto x = g;` fails in clang, but works in gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
auto (*x)() = &g;
```

should be legal as per the changes made by [P1972](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1972r0.html), in particular the change to [temp.deduct#funaddr-1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct#funcaddr-1)

> ... **If there is a target, the** The function template's function type and the specified target type are used as the types of P and A, and the deduction is done as described in 13.10.2.5. **Otherwise, deduction is performed with empty sets of types P and A.**

I've emphasized the text that was added in P1972. Note that now, if there is no specified target type, as in the case `auto (*)()` since the return type of this function is deduced, template argument deduction can still be performed. Previously, without a target type, the template arguments couldn't be deduced  when taking the address of `g`.

Of course, if the template arguments to `g` are specified, or the target type is specified, then it was always ok

```
void (*x)() = &g;        // ok, target is specified
auto (*x)() = &g<void>;  // ok, template parameters specified
```

Clang doesn't support P1972 [yet](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), hence the error.